# How can println print an object

Tags: java, list

```
{
  List list= new ArrayList();
  list.add("one");
  list.add("second");
  System.out.println(list);
}
```

How can the object "list" be used like it has been in the print statement? Don't we need to use the object to access a method to print the list?

Comment: This will prints out the List object's reference by default.

Comment: inside the `List` class the toString method is being overridden so that it will print all its contents rather than the address of the object.

Comment: well what does it mean for the the list object to be initialized to the Arraylist() function I thought nly constructors could be used to initialize an object? so shouldn it be List list= new List() ?

Comment: @Quirin no, `List`'s `.toString()` will print `[`, then its element's `.toString()` joined by a comma, then `]`

Comment: `new ArrayList` IS a constructor that creates a List object. (ArrayList implements List). Read up on polymorphism

Comment: so that means that if I were to create a class lets say XX and creat an object of that class say XX aa; then System.out.println(aa); will print the address of that object?

Answer (score 5):

`prinln(someObject)` will print out whatever is implemented in `someObject`'s `toString()` method.

Answer (score 2):

You can use toString() which is (supposed) to be implemented for all objects:

```
System.out.println(list.toString())
```

Note that you ought not to use the returned string as anything you can actually parse; it's really for a visual representation. It also doesn't need to *uniquely* represent the object.

When you write

```
System.out.println(list)
```

you are, in fact, using the `toString()` method implicitly.

Comment: `System.out.println(list.toString()) == System.out.println(list);`

Comment: so how does the compiler choose between printing toString and the arraylist?

Answer (score 1):

[**Docs Says about toString() in Collections:**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/AbstractCollection.html#toString%28%29)

> Returns a string representation of this collection. The string representation consists of a list of the collection's elements in the order they are returned by its iterator, enclosed in square brackets ("[]"). Adjacent elements are separated by the characters ", " (comma and space). Elements are converted to strings as by String.valueOf(Object).

Answer (score 1):

When we pass any object to println() method, it will implicitly call that object's **toString()** method. So, what is actually executed is

```
System.out.println( list.toString() );
```

ArrayList is inherited from the class java.util.AbstractCollection and that class has **toString()** method. So, in your case, that toString() should be executed.

That toString() method returns a string representation of this collection. The string representation consists of a list of the collection's elements in the order they are returned by its iterator, enclosed in square brackets ("[]"). Adjacent elements are separated by the characters ", " (comma and space). Elements are converted to strings as by String.valueOf(Object).

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your question and comments, I think your confusion ultimately stems from you being unsure how printing works. In general in such cases, I recommend to get the JDK sources and simply take look inside.

In this case, we would first go to the `System` class and check out the `out` member (because `println` is called on `System.out`):

```
public final class System {
     ...
     public final static PrintStream out = null;
```

Since we know now that `out` is a `PrintStream`, let's check out that class:

```
public class PrintStream extends FilterOutputStream
    implements Appendable, Closeable
{
    ...
    public void println(Object x) {
        String s = String.valueOf(x);
        synchronized (this) {
            print(s);
            newLine();
        }
    }
```

(we know it's calling this method, since the other `println` signatures don't match the type `List`)

OK, so we see that `println` converts the given `Object` (your `List` in this case) to a `String` using `String.valueOf(Object)`. Let's check out that method:

```
public final class String {
    ...
    public static String valueOf(Object obj) {
        return (obj == null) ? "null" : obj.toString();
    }
```

So now we know that your `List`'s `toString()` method is used to generate the output. As others have pointed out, it is overriden in `ArrayList` to provide the output you see.

Comment: Glad you like it. In general, don't be afraid to snoop around in the JDK - you won't break anything, and it's just Java code, same as any you'll see.

Answer (score 0):

It can be used like this because class List inherits the Object class, and the Object class has the toString() method, which means every object can be turned into a String.

Answer (score 0):

printing a list directly will give the the string representation of the list. 
If you want to access the objects in the list you need to use iterator or loops or advanced for loops for collections. 
e.g.

```
for(String s : list){
    System.out.println(s);
  }
```

Well you can study and try out all the list methods to modify it. e.g. add, remove.

Also if you are printing an object, then toString() method is implicitly called.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through all the items in the list in order to print them out. you can do this using a while loop of a for loop.

```
while (list.hasNext) {
  System.out.println((String) list.next());
```

}

```
for(String i in list){
   System.out.println(i) ;
```

}
Not sure if this is what your looking for but its an option.

Answer (score 0):

Yo need toString() method. when you print object Reference , by default toString() method is called. If you look at toString() method  by default it prints

```
 getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())
```

Now as per your requirements you can override this to print the values in list(String Class overrides it too)

Answer (score 0):

Here you are creating List interface.So it will allow to add duplicate values in list also.Also we can directly print object like System.out.println(obj);
And inside the List class the, toString method is being overridden so that it will print all its contents rather than the address of the object.

Answer (score 0):

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(myList.toArray()));